Javascript to scroll to element with ID
I've got a script that scrolls the page to the top when a form in an iframe has submitted and new content loads into the iframe.
document.querySelector("iframe").addEventListener("load", 
function() {
    window.scrollTo({
top: 0,
left: 0,
behavior: 'smooth'
});
});

Instead of scrolling to the top I need the page to scroll to a particular element with a specific ID. How would that code need to change?

Thank you @SyndRain. But I'm having problems combining this with the code I've got.

document.getElementById("here is your element ID").scrollIntoView();


Thank you. Are you able to tell me how to integrate this with the code I've already got?
